# Setup DLL doesnt run when CAB installs under CE6

Tags: c++, dll, installation, windows-ce, cab

I have a CAB file that installs our program to Windows CE.
I have a CAB (and platform configuration) for Windows CE 5 and 6.

Both CABs have their CE Setup DLL property pointing to the Primary Output of a Setup project.
Both CABs contain the exact same code (C++).

When installing the CE5 CAB it works perfectly and the custom setup actions are ran from the SetupDLL.
When installing the CE6 CAB the setup is not ran, however all the other files are unpacked as expected.

Can anyone shed any light to why this is happening?

All code and projects have been created and built using VS2005 (with all the latest service packs etc)

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this didn't work was because you have to compile the setup DLL separately for CE5 and CE6 - the code isn't totally cross platform compatible.